# How to reset a certain column values to zeros?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a beginner with google script and I am facing a challenge with  Google Sheets. The challenge is to write a function to reset a certain column's cells values to zeros. where I need it to rewrite any value was written in any cell to zero.

Like to reset the following:

[image]

To:

[image]

I tried this (Thanks to the gentlemen who answered):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("scm");
  var column = sh.getRange("d7:d14");
  sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1).setvalue(0);
  };
```

And the error appeared:
[ERROR1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qctUL.png)

```
function  myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("scm");
  var column = sh.getRange("d7:d14");
  const  Z = 0
  sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1),Z;
}
```

And the error appeared:
[ERROR2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHKVo.png)

I need help with last line, which its purpose to rewrite the desired mentioned above column's values to zero.

Comment: `sh.getRange("A1:A10").setValues(0)`

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief descriptio of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Howdy! The error informs that the `sheet` variable is not properly initiated. This may occurs because the sheet is not called *Schedule*. Could you please check that? Also please share the code in a text form, not in a picture.

Comment: Now I wrote the codes (thanks for the tip) , I made some edits, as I changed the sheet name, but a new error I can not get it solved which is 'Cannot convert 'Range' to int.'

Comment: Thank you Rubén for sharing the article.

Answer (score 0):

```
function resetColumn(col=1) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).clearContent();
}
```

regarding your update:

error1 issue:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("scm");
  sh.getRange("d7:d14")setValue(0);//just from row 7 to row 14
  //sh.getRange(1,4,sh.getLastRow()).setValue(0);//the whole column;
};
```

This version makes no sense to me:

```
function  myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("scm");
  var column = sh.getRange("d7:d14");
  const  Z = 0
  sh.getRange(1, column, sh.getLastRow(), 1),Z;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't set the cells to zero

Comment: Hi Cooper, I would like to thank you for your cooperation, I have tried something sommelier. kindly check the question updates and I would love to read your opinion.

Comment: In the code in your example `column` is not an integer so once you fix the problem that's causing the current error you will get another error about parameters that don't match the signature.  My guess is that the current problem may have nothing to do with your code I would just close the file and open it up again.

Comment: Something that you should keep in mind is that getValues always returns a 2d array even for a single cell, single row, or a single column.

Comment: I see, Anyway the issue you have mentioned has appeared, I start to believe that this program is not capable to satisfy my needs, I might try to apply if function to do the desired code. I made some updates in the question, I would appreciate to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I recommend you to use an approach as follows.

```js
function clearColumn() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var column = 2; // COLUMN B

  sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setValue(0);
}
```

First you should select the sheet in [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) with a combination of [`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive) and [`Sheet.getActiveSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet). From that point you can select the column with [`Sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) to change its value using [`Range.setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue). Please let me know if you have any doubt about this procedure.

Comment: Hi Mr. Jacques, I would like to thank you for your cooperation, and I feel I am close to getting the code that will achieve the result I need. I have tried something. Please check the question updates and sharing your opinion will be appreciated, Sir